# Encoding for RTF Text - Does One Exist?

Tags: apache-flex, excel, encoding, utf-8

I'm wondering if there is an encoding like UTF8/16 that can account for characters that are bold, italic, underlined, and super/sub-scripted? If not, is it under consideration by the powers that be?

Reason for the question is that I have a large excel file where many cells contain rtf text such as italics, bold, superscript; and I need to access the information on a row-by-row basis. I know I can save the file in html or xml, but I would like to import the data into MySQL - keeping the formatting - and then being able to access the data a row at a time.

I've considered using Markdown or Textile, but that means a whole lot of time changing each cell - we're talking about 5,000 records. Also, I want to continue to use Flex and I'm not sure if Flex can display html formatted text in their text controls because of their their text engine...

Cheers, 
Andy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ages ago, I wrote an RTF encoder. It does everything you want. I modeled it after "AlivePDF" so you can follow most of their documentation. Here is a link to the RTFlex library http://code.google.com/p/rtflex/ and the source code.

To get RTF to display in flex you need to take advantage of TLF. You don't say what version you're using but the new TLF framework is available in 4+. To do it properly, you'd need to write a converter to go from RTF to TLF. Robin Briggs explains this in more detail here: http://forums.adobe.com/thread/669151

There exists an HTML/plain text/TLF to TLF built into Flex, `TextConverter.importToFlow()` I think.